# Duplicate value in trigger

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

may I know why this code will produce duplicate output?

```
trigger pullCommentsApproval on Return_Shipment__c (before update) {
    
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        List<Return_Shipment__c> opptyList=[Select id, 
                                            (Select Id, 
                                             IsPending, 
                                             ProcessInstanceId, 
                                             TargetObjectId,
                                             StepStatus, 
                                             OriginalActorId, 
                                             ActorId, 
                                             RemindersSent,
                                             Comments, 
                                             IsDeleted, 
                                             CreatedDate,
                                             CreatedById, 
                                             SystemModstamp 
                                             From ProcessSteps where StepStatus = 'Approved' or StepStatus = 'Rejected'
                                             ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) 
                                            From Return_Shipment__c 
                                            WHERE Id IN : Trigger.new];
        
        // if (opptyList.size() > 0){
        Return_Shipment__c opp = opptyList[0];
        for(Return_Shipment__c opp1 : Trigger.new) {
            if(opp.id == opp1.id && opp1.Final_Approved__c) {
                if (opp.ProcessSteps.size() > 0) {
                    for (ProcessInstanceHistory processStep : opp.ProcessSteps) {
                        opp1.Approver_Comments__c += '/. Comments: ' + processStep.comments + ' . Status: ' + processStep.StepStatus + ' . Date: ' + processStep.CreatedDate;
                        opp1.Approved_Date1__c = DateTime.parse(system.now().format());
                        opp1.Approver_Comments3__c = 'aa'; //This is a dummy value & field only.
                        
                        break;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            break;
        }  
        // }
    }
}
```

here is the result:
[image]

It supposed to:
[image]

means no duplicate. Only the circle one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset the field before adding the new values, so it accumulates every time you run the trigger. Also, this code is not properly bulkified. Here's a fixed version:

```
trigger pullCommentsApproval on Return_Shipment__c (before update) {
    Map<Id, Return_Shipment__c> oppMap = new Map<Id, Return_Shipment__c>([
        Select 
        (Select
            IsPending, 
            ProcessInstanceId, 
            TargetObjectId,
            StepStatus, 
            OriginalActorId, 
            ActorId, 
            RemindersSent,
            Comments, 
            IsDeleted, 
            CreatedDate,
            CreatedById, 
            SystemModstamp 
            From ProcessSteps where StepStatus IN ('Approved','Rejected')
            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) 
        From Return_Shipment__c 
        WHERE Id IN : Trigger.new]);

    for(Return_Shipment__c opp: Trigger.new) {
        Return_Shipment__c opp1 = oppMap.get(opp.Id);
        opp.Approver_Comments__c = '';
        for (ProcessInstanceHistory processStep : opp1.ProcessSteps) {
            opp.Approver_Comments__c += '/. Comments: ' + processStep.comments + ' . Status: ' + processStep.StepStatus + ' . Date: ' + processStep.CreatedDate;
            opp.Approved_Date1__c = DateTime.parse(system.now().format());
            opp.Approver_Comments3__c = 'aa'; //This is a dummy value & field only.
        }
    }  
}
```